# Exacting form ids from a web form using Ruby or other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm using Net::HTTP.post_form in order to set a form's input values. However, the form values for the external site are dynamically generated. How can I extract the form names, and then also make sure the form was successfully submitted in the response message?

What I have so far:

```
uri = URI('http:://example.com')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'input_id1' = value 1... etc)
```

However, I need a way to parse out what input_id1's actual name is.

Is there a helper function in Ruby (or other languages) that automatically can retrieve an array of the web form params?
And how do I make sure (from the response result) that the form was submitted?

Comment: The URI might be usefull for you: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: If you want to parse a page there is no tool like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) You can parse pretty much anything web related using it. The documentation is pretty straight forward.